# Magento HTML email format not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to make magento contact form send as HTML email, I just changed the xml file on

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml
```

This block

```
<template>
            <email>
                <contacts_email_email_template translate="label" module="contacts">
                    <label>Contact Form</label>
                    <file>contact_form.html</file>
                    <type>text</type>
                </contacts_email_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
```

to

```
<template>
            <email>
                <contacts_email_email_template translate="label" module="contacts">
                    <label>Contact Form</label>
                    <file>contact_form.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </contacts_email_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
```

But the email still sending as text email, my magento version is 1.9.0.1,

anyone know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

The email is probably being sent as HTML, but the HTML template you are using doesn't contain any HTML markup.

take a look at contact_form.html - have you added any html markup?

On a separate note you should not be editing core files, you should override this rather than edit anything insiode core/*